# SQL to powerBI expression?

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax

How to write this expression in PowerBI

```
select distinct([date]),Temperature from Device47A8F where Temperature>25
```

Totally new to PowerBI. Is there any tool that can change the query from sql to PowerBI expression?

I have tried so many type of different type of expressions but getting error, Most of the time I am getting this:

```
The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value.
```

Need help, Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a sample Data? Anyway, I recommend you to look at sqlbi.com and eventually get one of the DAX books to starrt. Because the language DAX is hard to master and even to understand fully. You might do that through slicers or pickers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After I posted my answer, wondered if your expected result is get only one date by temperature, In other words, without repeated dates in your result set.

**A side note:** `select distinct([date]),Temperature from Device47A8F where Temperature>25` returns repeated dates since `DISTINCT` keyword evaluate distinct columns values specified in the `SELECT` statement, it doesn't return distinct values in a specific column even if you surround it with parenthesis.

Now what brings us here. What I can see in your error is that you are trying to use a `table-valued` (produces a table with multiple columns) expression in a measure which only accepts `scalar-valued` (calculate only one value).

Supposing you have a table like this:

[image]

Running your SQL query you will get the highlighted in yellow rows:

[image]

You can see `01/09/2016` date is repeated. If you want to create a `measure` you have to define what calculation you want to show for temperature. i.e, average, max or min etc.

In the below expression is being calculated the maximum temperature greater than 25 per date:

```
MaxTempGreaterThan25 =
CALCULATE ( MAX ( Device47A8F[Temperature] ), Device47A8F[Temperature] > 25 )
```

In this case the measure `MaxTempGreaterThan25` is calculated per date.

[image]

If you don't want to produce a measure but a table. In the Power BI Tool bar select `Modeling` tab and click `New Table` icon.

[image]

Use this expression:

```
MyTemperatureTable =
FILTER ( Device47A8F, Device47A8F[Temperature] > 25 )
```

It should produce a new table named `MyTemperatureTable` like this:

[image]

I recommend you learn some basics about DAX, it is pretty different from `SQL` / `T-SQL` and there are things you can't do depending on your model and data.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't need to write any code if your objective is to show the result in a Power BI visual e.g. a table.  Power BI naturally aggregates data if the datatype is numeric (e.g. Temperature).

I would just add a Table visual on a Report page and add the Date and Temperature columns to it. Then in **Visualizations / Fields / Values** I would click the little down-arrow on the Temperature field and set the Aggregation e.g. **Maximum**.  Then in **Visualizations / Fields / Filters** I would click the little down-arrow on the Temperature field and set the Filter e.g. **is greater than: 25**

Hard-coded solutions are unlikely to survive the next question from your users e.g. "but what if I want to see Temperature > 24? Or 20? Or 30?"